# VisualStudio c3861

Tags: c++

Can u help me with error of my code? I dont know what mean c3861 and how to delete error :(

```
int main()
{
    string File[101];
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        File[i] = "liczby" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
        ifstream f(File[i]);
        if (f.good()) {
            wczytywanie(File[i]);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my function of read line from .txt file

```
void wczytywanie(string filename) {
    ifstream plik(filename);
    int x, y;
    while (plik >> x >> y) {
        cout << x << " " << y;
    }
    plik.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the complete error? C3861 is ['identifier not found'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3861?view=vs-2019). So, it may help to know _which_ identifier cannot be found.

Comment: Please try to show a complete [mcve] that replicates the error, and also include the complete and full error output from the compiler (copy-pasted as text, in the question itself).

Comment: On an unrelated note, array indexes start at *zero*. Please make it a habit of using `0` as starting index in your own code.

Comment: I assume `wczytywanie()` is unknown in `main()`? You have to declare this function prior use in `main()`. This is usually done making corresponding header files to sources...

Comment: Here is error 
Error C3861 "wczytywanie": identyfikatora nie odnaleziono c:\users\curio\source\repos\punkty\punkty\punkty.cpp 18

Comment: There's an `edit` link in your question. Please use it to improve your question. And lastly please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Ok, it's works <3